# no operator "<<" matches

Tags: c++, dictionary, c++03

```
#include<iostream>
#include<set>
#include<unordered_map>

using namespace std;

typedef long Node;

typedef unordered_map<Node, set<Node> > Dothi;

Dothi g;

while (n--)
{
    Node u, i;
    int choose;
    cin >> choose;
    if (choose == 1)
    {
        cin >> u >> i;
        cout << (Lienke(u, i) ? "TRUE" : "FALSE");
    }

    checkCase2 = false;

    if (choose == 2)
    {
        cin >> u;
        for (  auto n = g[u].begin(); n!=g[u].end();++n)
        {
            cout << n <<" "; //Error here, cant cout n
            checkCase2 = true;
        }
```

- I can't cout below the line: "for(  auto n = g[u].begin(); n!=g[u].end();++n )".
- It says: "no operator "<<" matches these operands".
- I'm allowed to use c++2003

Comment: n is an iterator. Try using *n: cout << *n <<" ";

Comment: Thank you, i tried and it worked, but the system said that: "ISO C++ forbids declaration of ‘n’ with no type ".

Comment: @MartinHoang C++03 does not have `auto`.

Comment: You're going to have to typedef the iterator for your map as well, instead of using auto. If you move to C++11, you will have both auto, as well as the new loop for (auto& n : g[u]), which is much easier to write, as well as giving you n as the variable itself and not an iterator.

Comment: It has auto, but in c++03 it's a storage class specifier, and not cought as an invalid keyword.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to print an iterator `n`. Since this is not implemented you get a compiler error. What I think you what is the following:

```
std::cout << std::distance(g[u].begin(), n) << std::endl;
```

This will print the index you are working with. You will need include the header `<iterator>`.

If you what to print the element (`node` aka `long`) at that index then use the dereference operator (`*`) like so:

```
std::cout << *n << std::endl;
```

**Update:**

Since you are using C++03, the `auto` keyword is not allowed for type deduction. You should then use (when declaring `n` in the for-loop):

```
Dothi::iterator n = g[u].begin();
```

Answer (score 3):

If what you wanted was to print a value under the given iterator then you must use dereference operator on it:

```
cout << *n <<" ";
        ^ ~~~~ !
```